# Tree with well disposed labels and edges

Tags: tikz-trees, forest

I would like to do a tree like this :

[image: Good tree]

But I'm only able to do this :

[image: Bad tree]

with the following code :

`\begin{forest} for tree={grow=north, parent anchor=north,child anchor=south}  [a[b[c]]] \path[fill=red] (.parent anchor) circle[radius=2pt];  \path[fill=blue](!1.child anchor) circle[radius=2pt]; \end{forest}`

Comment: would you like to use tikz or is only forest to be used

Comment: The code I wrote is inspired from the documentation of the Forest package (page 45) where they show how to mix Forest and Tikz. I don't have any preference between them, both would be perfect !

Comment: @jsbibra For trees, `forest` is to be preferred over the base TikZ tree methods.  `forest` *is* TikZ but with a lot of features specifically designed for trees.

Comment: Please make me clear: you like to have the first image in question (such images are in article in given link), not the second one. Do I'm right?

Comment: Yes exactly, I would like to reproduce the first image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that use the pure TikZ is the simplest way:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\tikzset{
    node distance= 4mm and 2mm,
    arr/.style = {thick, draw=#1},
    arr/.default = red,
    dot/.style = {circle, draw, very thin, fill, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, 
                  minimum size=3pt,
                  label=right:$#1$,
                  node contents={}},
    every label/.append style = {font=\scriptsize, inner sep=1pt}
        }
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\node (a) [dot=a];
\node (b) [dot=b,above=of a];
\node (c) [dot=c,above=of b];
\draw[arr] (a) -- (b);
\draw[arr=green] (b) -- (c);
   \end{tikzpicture}
   
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\node (a) [dot=a];
\node (b) [dot=b,above right=of a];
\node (c) [dot=c,below right=of b];
\draw[arr] (a) -- (b);
\draw[arr=green] (b) -- (c);
   \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image] [image]

Comment: Great it works perfectly for me ! Thank you very much !

Comment: @Enzo, you are welcome! Thanks on this site are normally given via upvotes answer or even accept it (by clicking on up-pen ad check mark at top left side of answer).